# Is there a way to inspect Sequential Workflow in Windows Workflow?

Tags: workflow-foundation, sequential-workflow

A state machine workflow has the StateMachineWorkflowInstance class that you can use to inspect the current state of the workflow, get legal transitions, etc... 
Is there something like that for sequential workflows? I would like to have an easy way to programmaticaly find out what state the workflow is currently in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflow tracking will five you a lot of information about the current state of your sequential workflow. It can even extract custom data from the workflow and store it as part of the tracking data if you want. By default it tracks all state changes for the workflow itself as well as all activities inside it.

The SqlTrackingQuery object helps in getting tracking data out of the database but it is straightforward to write your own SQL queries as well.

http://wiki.windowsworkflowfoundation.eu/default.aspx/WF/SqlTrackingService.html